# c++ - run on an object, operator overloading () with index

Tags: c++, operators

I have a class to represent two-dimensional array and I want to use () operator for example,

```
Array arr;
arr(2,5) = 17; // I want to assign 17 as element in 2nd row and 5th column.
```

I tried something like that: (but is not working)

```
void operator(int m, int n)(int num) {
    int m, n;
    p[m][n] = num;
}
```

i have an operator = (this working):

```
void operator=(const Array& other) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            p[i][j] = other.p[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

`Array` class has `T**` as private member.

How can I overload `()` operator to access elements in array

Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

You need to build something like

`int& operator()(int m, int n)`

which returns a *reference* to the array element, that you can modify through that reference at the calling site.

Don't forget to build the `const` overload

`const int& operator()(int m, int n) const`

so you can use similar syntax at a call site for element access for a `const` object.

---

Finally, for your assignment operator, you ought not make it `const` (have you made `p mutable`?), and you should return a reference to self to help *compound assignment*:

```
Array& operator=(const Array& other){
    // Your existing code
    return *this;
}
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for sorting out this mess.

Comment: One hour and six upvotes before anyone noticed. Nice :p

Comment: @Quentin: You see, all this criticism that SO gets in "it getting nasty" is completely unfounded.